# N Queen with predefined queen(s)

Tags: algorithm, np, n-queens

The origin N-Queen problem is about placing N Queens on a N*N board.

However, I have been questioned from one of my academic friends:

Is there any NP-completeness proof for the N Queen problem with predefined queen(s)?

The definition is:

Assumption:

1. N = 8,
2. The board already placed 3 queens on (0,0), (2,7), (7,4).

Question:

1. Are there any polynomial algorithm(s) to know the board does have / not have solution(s)?
2. Or the fastest algorithm on the above question?

Appendix:

1. Explicit Solution will not work because of predefined queen(s).

[An Image Example Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzHEC.png)

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

> Complexity of n-Queens Completion
>
> DOI https://doi.org/10.1613/jair.5512
>
> Ian P. Gent
>
> Christopher Jefferson
>
> Peter Nightingale
>
> **Abstract**
>
> The n-Queens problem is to place n chess queens on an n by n
>   chessboard so that no two queens are on the same row, column or
>   diagonal. The n-Queens Completion problem is a variant, dating to
>   1850, in which some queens are already placed and the solver is asked
>   to place the rest, if possible. We show that n-Queens Completion is
>   both NP-Complete and #P-Complete. A corollary is that any
>   non-attacking arrangement of queens can be included as a part of a
>   solution to a larger n-Queens problem. We introduce generators of
>   random instances for n-Queens Completion and the closely related
>   Blocked n-Queens and Excluded Diagonals Problem. We describe three
>   solvers for these problems, and empirically analyse the hardness of
>   randomly generated instances. For Blocked n-Queens and the Excluded
>   Diagonals Problem, we show the existence of a phase transition
>   associated with hard instances as has been seen in other NP-Complete
>   problems, but a natural generator for n-Queens Completion did not
>   generate consistently hard instances. The significance of this work is
>   that the n-Queens problem has been very widely used as a benchmark in
>   Artificial Intelligence, but conclusions on it are often disputable
>   because of the simple complexity of the decision problem. Our results
>   give alternative benchmarks which are hard theoretically and
>   empirically, but for which solving techniques designed for n-Queens
>   need minimal or no change.

Comment: Thanks for ur speedy reply and the paper is very useful！